# Mapstruct how to map from composition to inheritance?

Tags: inheritance, composition, mapstruct

On one side, I've an object A that extends B.

```
   public class A extends B {
        private boolean anotherAttr;
   }
```

And on the other side, an object C that has a D attribute

```
public class C implements Serializable {
    private D common;
    private boolean anotherAttr;
}
```

I already have a mapstruct method that map from D to B

```
public abstract B mapBFromD(D pOrigin);
```

Now I need to map A from C

```
public abstract A mapAFromC(C pOrigin);
```

How can i re-use mapBFromD instead of having to manually declare every B attributes ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't really reuse the `mapBFromD` method because that method creates an instance of `B` and you can't assign that to `A`.

One thing that you can do is to use `.` to map into the current target

```
@Mapping(target = ".", source = "common")
public abstract A mapAFromC(C pOrigin);
```

With this however, you will have to define any non implicit mappings between `D` and `A`.